Is there a way to pass a context from a page to a showDialog() in flutter?
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => CounterBloc(),
      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, CounterState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
                title: Text(title),
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                                    content:
                                        BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, CounterState>(
                                      builder: (context, state) {
                                        return Container(
                                          width: 1000,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                          ),
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment
                                                        .spaceBetween,
                                                children: [
                                                  ElevatedButton(
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      BlocProvider.of<
                                                                  CounterBloc>(
                                                              context)
                                                          .add(
                                                        DecrementCounterEvent(),
                                                      );
                                                    },
                                                    child: const Text('-'),
                                                  ),
                                                  Text('${state.counter}'),
                                                  ElevatedButton(
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      BlocProvider.of<
                                                                  CounterBloc>(
                                                              context)
                                                          .add(
                                                        IncrementCounterEvent(),
                                                      );
                                                    },
                                                    child: const Text('+'),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ));
                        },
                        child: const Text('Push me')),
                    Text(
                      '${state.counter}',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

I'm building a flutter app using the Bloc pattern. I am encountering a problem with dialog boxes like below. I get the error: "ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, CounterState> Widget". How then can I pass the right context to the showdialog()?


The issue you were facing is due to the fact that the context for the page and the context for the AlertDialog are different. Because of this, BlocProvider tries to find the CounterBloc in the widget tree of the AlertDialog, which results in a "Provider Not Found" exception. This is the same case for bottom sheets as well to overcome this issue wrap your child of dialog child with BlocProvider.value

 showDialog(
                context:context,
                builder: (_){
                  return BlocProvider.value(
                        value: BlocProvider.of<CounterBloc>(context),
                        child: AlertDialog(
                     // rest all code same
                  )
                )
                }
               )


BlocProvider to provide a CounterBloc define in MyApp with home as...
home: BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => CounterBloc(),
        child: MyHomePage(),
      )

And remove BlocProvider from MyHomePage.
